# 2km grid with rast() and terra in R

Tags: r, grid, terra

How would I construct a 2km grid with the `rast` function in the `terra` package in `R`

text.txt=

```
name,long,lat,water_level,elevation,depth
EM_01,18.553392,-34.07027,14.4,20.358,63.0
EM_27,18.574777,-34.068709,16.196,19.966,48.0
EM_29,18.613985,-34.053271,18.766,25.477,39.0
EM_20,18.654089,-34.045177,20.102,36.502,45.0
```

with R code:

```r
library(sf) # 'simple features' representations of spatial objects
library(terra) 

file = 'text.txt'
#-- import
cfaq <- read.csv(file, header = 1, sep = ',', dec = '.') #sep = '\t',
#- set as a spatial feature with xy coords an existing projection
cfaq.sf <- st_as_sf(cfaq, coords=c("long", "lat"), crs = 4326) #wgs84
#- transform to local crs
cfaq.sf <- st_transform(cfaq.sf, crs = 32734) #utm 34s

(n.col <- length(seq.e <- seq(min.x <- floor(min(st_coordinates(cfaq.sf)[,"X"])/1000)*1000,
                              max.x <- ceiling(max(st_coordinates(cfaq.sf)[,"X"])/1000)*1000, by=1000)))
(n.row <- length(seq.n <- seq(min.y <- floor(min(st_coordinates(cfaq.sf)[,"Y"])/1000)*1000,
                              max.y <- ceiling(max(st_coordinates(cfaq.sf)[,"Y"])/1000)*1000, by=1000)))

#we want a 2km grid
grid2km <- rast(nrows = n.row, ncols = n.col,
                xmin=min.x, xmax=max.x,
                ymin=min.y, ymax=max.y, crs = st_crs(cfaq.sf)$proj4string,
                resolution = 2000, names="waterLevel")

values(grid2km) <- NA_real_
```

then

```r
class(grid2km) 
summary(grid2km)
st_crs(grid2km) #or st_crs(grid2km)$crs or st_crs(grid2km)$proj4string
```

should return a `SpatRaster`, an empty grid and the crs but the crs is `NA`.

After this

```r
plot(grid2km); grid()
```

with an error:

```
Error: [plot] no values
Traceback:

1. plot(grid2km)
2. plot(grid2km)
3. .local(x, y, ...)
4. plot(x, 1, maxcell = maxcell, main = main[1], mar = mar, ...)
5. plot(x, 1, maxcell = maxcell, main = main[1], mar = mar, ...)
6. .local(x, y, ...)
7. .prep.plot.data(x, type = type, maxcell = maxcell, cols = col, 
 .     mar = mar, draw = TRUE, plg = plg, pax = pax, legend = isTRUE(legend), 
 .     axes = isTRUE(axes), coltab = coltab, facts = facts, interpolate = smooth, 
 .     levels = levels, range = range, colNA = colNA, ...)
8. .as.raster.continuous(out, x, type)
9. error("plot", "no values")
10. stop("[", f, "] ", emsg, ..., call. = FALSE)

Error in int_abline(a = a, b = b, h = h, v = v, untf = untf, ...): plot.new has not been called yet
Traceback:

1. grid()
2. abline(v = at, col = col, lty = lty, lwd = lwd)
3. int_abline(a = a, b = b, h = h, v = v, untf = untf, ...)
```

how do I create an empty grid with the `rast()` function in the `terra()` package, and plot it, in `R` please?

Comment: Why is `$proj4string` commented out? `rast()` expects character for `crs`.  Nevertheless, I can't reproduce this error  with terra_1.7-39 & sf_1.0-13 in Windows, with with `crs = st_crs(cfaq.sf)` it fails because of `unable to find an inherited method for function ‘crs’ for signature ‘"crs"’` (which is expected) and with `crs = st_crs(cfaq.sf)$proj4string` or  `crs = st_crs(cfaq.sf)$wkt` it just works .